# C file compiles without -lm when pow() is in main() but not when pow() is within a function

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I have a program which will run when compiled (without -lm flag) when the pow() function is out in the main() function, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{

    double test = pow(16, 5);
    printf("%f\n", test);

}
```

It compiles and runs fine:

```
$ gcc 2-3.c -o 2-3 && ./2-3
1048576.000000
```

However when pow() is inside a function the program won't compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double in_function(int val);

int main(void)
{

    double test;

    test = in_function(5);
    printf("%f\n", test);

}


double in_function(int val) {

    double n;

    n = pow(16, val);

    return n;

}
```

Try to compile:

```
$ gcc 2-3.c -o 2-3 && ./2-3
/tmp/ccCEDMJ8.o: In function `in_function':
2-3.c:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I realize that I need to add the -lm flag to gcc to make it work, but I didn't need to add -lm to the first program at all. Why is that?

Comment: Compile-time evaluation? In your first example, everything needed to compute the result is known at compile time.

Comment: `pow(16, 5)` is computed by the compiler (at compile time); `pow(16, val)` must be computed by the code in the math library (at run time).

Comment: Try `double in_function(void) { return pow(16, 5); }`